# Pagination with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with over 800K records. This table needs to be "grouped by" a certain column. An example would be:

[image]

However, with pagination, things get complicated. I want to show 50 rows for every group.

This means that if I have the following data:

| Id | Color | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Paper #1 |
| 2 | Red | Paper #2 |
| 3 | Red | Paper #3 |
| 4 | Green | Paper #4 |
| 5 | Green | Paper #5 |
| 6 | Green | Paper #6 |
| 7 | Green | Paper #7 |

And I wanted to get `2` items for every group per page (instead of `50`, for the sake of this example), on page 1 I'd have:

| Id | Color | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Paper #1 |
| 2 | Red | Paper #2 |
| 4 | Green | Paper #4 |
| 5 | Green | Paper #5 |

And at page 2 I'd have:

| Id | Color | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Red | Paper #3 |
| 6 | Green | Paper #6 |
| 7 | Green | Paper #7 |

My current SQL query (SQL Server) for pagination is the following:

```sql
SELECT
   * 
from
   [Order] 
ORDER BY
[From] ASC
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsOfPage ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Not a complete answer, but start with `SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Color ORDER BY Name) AS Row FROM Order WHERE Row BETWEEN (@PageNumber -1 )*@RowsOfPage+1 AND @PageNumber*@RowsOfPage ORDER BY Color,Row`

Comment: what is the RDBMS ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR SQL Server

Comment: `This table needs to be "grouped by" a certain column` What is that `certain column` for the sample data that you posted ?

Comment: @Squirrel Color

Comment: Why are you doing `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` ? You shouldn't do that because your results will have undefined order (so results will come back nondeterminisitcally with very different orderings once SQL Server does anything to its on-disk paging structure). You should order by the PK (or clustered index) if you don't have any other columns to order by.

Comment: @Dai That is true. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(Id int, Color varchar(10), Name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO Orders(Id,Color,Name) VALUES 
  (1, 'Red', 'Paper #1'),
  (2, 'Red', 'Paper #2'),
  (3, 'Red', 'Paper #3'),
  (4, 'Green', 'Paper #4'),
  (5, 'Green', 'Paper #5'),
  (6, 'Green', 'Paper #6'),
  (7, 'Green', 'Paper #7');
```

This query will do:

```
DECLARE @PageNum int = 1;
DECLARE @PageSize int = 2;
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Color ORDER BY Name) AS Row
  FROM Orders
) t1
WHERE Row BETWEEN ((@PageNum-1)*@PageSize+1) AND (@PageNum*@PageSize)
ORDER BY Color,Name
```

Page 1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/748cc2/27/0
[image]

Page 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/748cc2/25/0
[image]

Comment: This works. However, with a very large table, it seems extremely slow. Is this due to using `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: I would have to take a look at the explain.  Could be any number of factors, some of which might be easily fixed -- such as pre-computing the start/end rows outside of the query.  SQL Server might not be able to deduce that it should be generating an index range, or perhaps you are missing a good index for it to use.

Comment: Since this is a static table that will never change, I'm able to create a Column called Row which contains the row #, and create a unique index on that column. However, I'm unsure how I would use that column in the query you provided above. I am pretty sure ROW_NUMBER() is the cause of how slow the query takes to execute.